# CABasicAnimation inside UICollectionViewCells finish offscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, core-animation

I am placing custom CABasicAnimation animation inside UICollectionViewCells. The intention is that the animation for each cell will be triggered individually once the cell appears onscreen. My approach is to implement a function that sets up a CABasicAnimation on the cell class. I am calling that from the controller's willDisplayCell.

This approach works for all reused cells. However, all the cells that are initially loaded for the controller will finish the animation immediately (offscreen) and not according to animation timing. What might be the issue?

```
// Cell

-(void)animate {
    [CATransaction begin]; {
        // My timed animations (CABasicAnimation)
    } [CATransaction commit];
}

// Controller

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [((CustomCell*)cell) animate]; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try collectionView reloadData in your ViewDidAppear? i think is better solution and less hacky, also your solution will delay all cells animations, please let me know if solves you issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by applying the following change. Feels like a hack but at least it works.

```
// Controller

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [((CustomCell*)cell) animate];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your Cell class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    [self animate];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this did not affect the issue in question in anyway and I fail to see how it could have.